# Desktop Sharing in java

Tags: java, rmi

I want to create a very simple RMI code which just share the desktop.

I have created my classes and also remote interface.in the Share class ,I have an execute method which will return the image of the client's desktop.but I don't know that how can I get that image ?or how can i store it?
please help me,thanks.

Share class:

```
class Share implements Task<DesktopPaneUI>,Serializable{
public Share(){

}

public DesktopPaneUI execute() {

}
```

}

Task class:

```
public interface  Task<T> {

T execute();
  }
```

Comment: so you are actually asking how to do a screenshot in java?

Comment: The code as posted seems pretty solid, I'm not sure I'd mess with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.*
import java.awt.image.*


BufferedImage screenShot = new Robot().createScreenCapture(
        new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize())
)
```